# Download file and place in drive C OR drive D, etc

Tags: c#

People have their main hard drives listed differently. Due to my program reaching people all over the world, I would like to have a picture download and placed in their **Picture** folder, even when they have different drives.

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile("www.Example.com\Picture1.jpeg", @"C:\Users\XXX\Pictures\Picture1.jpeg");
}
```

This works to download and place in "C" drive. However, what if the user doesn't have a "C" drive, rather a "D" drive?

Simply put, I would like to download this picture, to reach everyone's **Picture** folder, no matter if it's drive "C", drive "D", etc.

Comment: So you want it to magically decide? Why not put it in a well known place, like pictures, or download

Comment: I Want the Program To Decide where to Place It, Based off of the User's Own Drive Setup.

Comment: I Can Place it in Pictures, that isn't the point though...

Comment: So breaking this problem down in to the smallest part, what do you think you need to search the internet for? What topics do you think would help you achieve detecting if a drive exists

Comment: Question is, This Code is running to only place the image in Drive C. This Will Not Work If There computer's main OS is on Drive D.. Etc..

Comment: Maybe how to [determine if a drive exists in C#](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=how+to+determine+if+a+drive+exists+in+C%23&oq=how+to+determine+if+a+drive+exists+in+C%23&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.647j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), or [how to get the OS drive C#](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=how+to+get+the+OS+drive+C%23&oq=how+to+get+the+OS+drive+C%23&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.438j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: lets us know what you come up with, also, what if you don't have permission to write to these drives, what are you going to do? [how to check if i have permission to write to a directory C#](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=how+to+check+if+i+have+permision+to+write+to+a+directory+C%23&oq=how+to+check+if+i+have+permision+to+write+to+a+directory+C%23&aqs=chrome..69i57.11671j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Also while you are researching the interwebs, you might want to check out [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [WRITING THE PERFECT QUESTION](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: also...is this a windows GUI desktop application (wpf or forms)...jim's answer is a start...but its better to give the user a default directory and then let them override it

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures`

Eg.

```
// Sample for the Environment.GetFolderPath method
using System;

class Sample 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("GetFolderPath: {0}", 
                 Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System));
    }
}
```

It doesn't make any assumptions about where 'Pictures' is.  Is that what you are looking for?

Related info https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Exactly, Using Environment.GetfolderPath, How Can I Download A Picture and Place in a Pictures Directory?

Comment: Have a look at your existing code in your question @RyanEllis. See the second parameter to `DownloadFile`? Have a think about how to use Jim's answer to change that parameter. Also look up `Path.Combine`.